# How to fix this curried function in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

The following example expands upon the example shown in this [swift-evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md) link, which describes only one parameter per argument list.  Any suggestion on how to fix a two parameter argument list?

```
// Before: (yields warning)
func curried(x: Int)(y: String, z:String) -> Float {
    return Float(x) + Float(y)! + Float(z)!
}

// After: (this is not working)
func curried(x: Int) -> (String, String) -> Float {
    return {(y: String, z: String) -> Float in
        return Float(x) + Float(y)! + Float(z)!
    }
}
```

Xcode 7.3 still reports the second method as "Curried function declaration syntax will be removed in a future version of Swift; use a single parameter list."

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The second method compiles without warnings and works as expected in Xcode 7.3.

Comment: @MartinR There's a bug in 7.3 where a warning doesn't go away even when the code has been fixed. He probably pasted in the first version, got the warning, replaced it with the second version, and got the bug where the old warning remains. Hence my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the Xcode 7.3 warning about the second version. If you clean out the build folder, the warning will probably go away. More important, the second version *does* work — it compiles in Swift 3, which is all that matters.

Comment: Gosh, it does work. The above example code is a distilled version of a larger method I'm trying to fix and it appears I did - just needed to clean out the build (thoroughly).